# perl script to monitor & restart listener hangs on nohup waiting for carriage return

Tags: perl, nohup

I have a tcp/ip listener written in java that is run for multiple 'sites' each with their own port.  The developer who wrote this listener did so as a standalone so I have to manage each via a start_comtrol.sh script which is quite tedious.  I'm new to perl, but I wrote a quick script today to check each pidfile compare to make sure the process is running and attempt to restart if not as shown below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sites = qw / FOO BAR FOO2 /;

foreach (@sites) {
    my $pidfile = "/usr/local/sbin/listener/$_/pid.file";
    my $start_comtrol = "/usr/local/sbin/listener/$_/start_comtrol.sh";
    open my $file, '<', $pidfile or die 'Could not open file:  ' . $!;
    my $pid = do { local $/; <$file> };
    close $file;
    my $exists = kill 0, $pid;
        if ( $exists ) {
            print "The running process for $_ is $pid\n"; #temp print to screen for debugging
            # Do Nothing
        }
        else {
            exec $start_comtrol;
    }
}
```

Each start_comtrol.sh script is identical in it's contents:

```
#!/bin/ksh
export CLASSPATH=.:ojdbc6.jar:Base.jar:ojdbc14.jar:log4j.jar
#export CLASSPATH=/home/aspira/controller/ojdbc6.jar:/home/aspira/controller/Base.jar:/home/aspira/controller/ojdbc14.jar
nohup java com.aspira.comtrol.listener.BaseListener  &
echo "$!" > pid.file
```

The script runs just fine when the process is found running, however if the process isn't running and it attempts to start it via the exec $start_comtrol.sh it encounters nohup waiting for carriage return and doesn't move on to the next variable in the sites array.

```
The running process for FOO is 19401

The running process for BAR is 1228

[root@isildur]# nohup: appending output to `nohup.out'
```

What's the best way to handle this so it doesn't hang up on the irrelevant prompt from nohup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) function, not `exec()`

From the doc for [`exec()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html):

> The exec function executes a system command and never returns; use
>   system instead of exec if you want it to return.

Try doing `system( $start_comtrol )` instead.

Comment: Changing to system is a step in the right direction.  What I'm noticing now is if only one listener is down it will restart properly, however if multiple are down, it attempts to restart the first down one it seems X the number of $sites that are down.  I.e. if both FOO and BAR are down and it sees FOO first, in FOO's logs you'll see ` Baselistener 
[2013-07-10 15:09:38,067] - Server started on port 4000
[2013-07-10 15:09:40,156] -  Unable to initialize the application. Check App properties, db settings or socket port. Address already in use`  was Foreach the wrong choice causing this loop?

Comment: "address already in use" makes it sound like there is already a listener running, which means the contents of your pid file is stale.  do a `ps -ef` and kill all of the running listeners, and then manually clear out the pid files and try restarting.  also (unrelated, but important), keep in mind that doing `kill -0 $pid` will tell you if there is a process with $pid running, but just because there is a process with that $pid doesn't necessarily mean it's your listener.